# schedule a message driven bean to access a queue during certain times?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, jms

1) **Can you schedule a message driven bean to access a queue only at certain times?**

For example, user has two contact options - between 9am-5pm and 5pm-10pm. I'd like to have two MDB one that is only active from 9am-5pm and the other at 3pm-10pm.

Both queues have messages sent to them throughout the day but I'd only like to process them at the specific times.

Ideally **@Schedule** would work but unfortunately it doesn't.

Using Glassfish 3.1.2 and ActiveMQ 5.5.1 but I'm pretty sure it's not an implementation specific question.

**Edit 1**

Code

```
@MessageDriven(
    activationConfig = {
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "jms/queue/amqmsg")
})
public class ExampleMessageBean implements MessageListener {

@Schedule(second="*", minute="*", hour="9-17", persistent = false)
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    try {
        System.out.println("We've received a message: " + message.getJMSMessageID());

        System.out.println("\n\n Message\n\n" + message);

    } catch (JMSException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Getting error on deployment. I don't think it's possible for @Schedule to be used in this way. Can anyone confirm?

```
SEVERE: Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer load method java.lang.RuntimeException: EJB Container initialization error
at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:242)
at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:299)
at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:105)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.load(ModuleInfo.java:186)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:264)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:460)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
 Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: Invalid @Timeout or @Schedule signature for: public void com.name.mdb.ExampleMessageBean.onMessage(javax.jms.Message) @Timeout or @Schedule method must return void and be a no-arg method or take a single javax.ejb.Timer param
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.processEjbTimeoutMethod(BaseContainer.java:2219)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.<init>(BaseContainer.java:743)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.MessageBeanContainer.<init>(MessageBeanContainer.java:142)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.ContainerFactoryImpl.createContainer(ContainerFactoryImpl.java:121)
at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:230)
... 33 more

   SEVERE: Exception while loading the app
   INFO: No timers to be deleted for id: 87558812344647680
   SEVERE: Exception while loading the app : EJB Container initialization error
   javax.ejb.EJBException: Invalid @Timeout or @Schedule signature for: public void com.test.mdb.ExampleMessageBean.onMessage(javax.jms.Message) @Timeout or @Schedule method must return void and be a no-arg method or take a single javax.ejb.Timer param
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.processEjbTimeoutMethod(BaseContainer.java:2219)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.<init>(BaseContainer.java:743)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.MessageBeanContainer.<init>(MessageBeanContainer.java:142)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.ContainerFactoryImpl.createContainer(ContainerFactoryImpl.java:121)
at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:230)
at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:299)
at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:105)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.load(ModuleInfo.java:186)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:264)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:460)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: Can you add expression & its result when used @Schedule, why it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Schedule doesnt like being called on your method which has the message param. How would it know this argument.

Just add the items to a queue and process seperately.

```
@MessageDriven(
    activationConfig = {
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "jms/queue/amqmsg")
})
public class ExampleMessageBean implements MessageListener {

private BlockingQueue<Message> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Message>() ; 

@Schedule(second="*", minute="*", hour="9-17", persistent = false)
public void process()
{
    //process queue here. 
}
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    try {
        System.out.println("We've received a message: " + message.getJMSMessageID());
        queue.add(message); 
        System.out.println("\n\n Message\n\n" + message);

    } catch (JMSException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this and sorry for the delay in responding. I knew when I asked the question my understanding of the process was off. Thanks for  clearing it up.